# Как можно запустить скрипт python на странице ( Django)

Tags: python, django

Есть самодельные скрипты которые выполняют рутинные задачи. Начал изучать Django. Нужно/хочу сделать кнопочку на html странице, нажав на которую запустится нужный мне скрипт и вернет на страницу результат выполнения.
Собственно вопрос в следующем никак не могу понять как это сделать. Может кто подсказать куда копать или показать пример такого действия?

Comment: Кнопка при клике пошлет запрос на сервер (например, ajax) на конкретный url, добавите в django обработки для того url, в обработчике запустите код из вашего скрипта

Comment: Стоит обратить внимание на то, как долго отрабатывает ваш скрипт. Если, например, скрипт ходит на сторонние сайты и парсит там какую-то информацию, то он может попросту повесить вашу вьюху, которая отдает респонс и пользователь вообще не получит никакого ответа из-за тайм аута.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов решения (пример):

Во `views.py`

```py
def own_func(request):
    context = {'useful_value': 1}
    if request.method == "POST":
        run_any_script()
    return render(request, 'your_html_page.html', context)
```

Простенькая функция, которая передает на страницу переменную `useful_value = 1` (повторюсь как пример), и при нажатии на кнопку на странице, которая имеет метод `POST`, выполняет какой-то скрипт (что там, ваша фантазия).

Answer (score 0):

1. сделать html форму которая отправляет запрос.

```
<form action="{% url 'parser' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

2. прописать путь до метода в urls.py

```
    path('parser/', views.parser, name='parser'),
```

3. Написать метод который будет парсить(вызывать парсер).

```
    def parser(request, *args, **kwargs);
        resp = start_parser(**kwargs)
        return render(request, 'page.html', {'resp': resp})
```

Естественно не упуская прочие условия на тип метода и авторизован ли юзер...